# Do all female cats have longer fur around their abdomen rather than around the rest of their body?

Tags: cats, health, breeds

My cat has regular short fur around her body but at her abdomen (more like at her bladder) she has longer fur, a family member told me it's because she is becoming a grown up by the days and the long fur around her abdomen is their to protect her abdomen more, because her body is getting ready for mating and pregnancy procedures. My cat is a mixed breed so I'm thinking it can be due to the admixture of breeds she's brought up to have.

So do all female cats have longer fur at their abdomen rather than the rest of their body? Or is it probably because she is a mixed breed?

[image]

You can see the fur around her bladder part is like floating, while the rest of her body has shorter fur.

Comment: I cannot confirm this as I am not an expert on animals however, we have had 5 female cats and 2 male cats in my house.  Both the males don't have the longer fur as you described (though one does have a belly XD).  Most of my females have the longer fur there that you refer.  I say most as there are 2 cats I don't recall if they do or do not and 1 has since passed.  I would say though it is fair to assert your theory to be true.

Comment: Is that fur longer? Or is it just standing up because of the skin angle? Their bellies are flexible and without bone behind them, especially if the cat has a little extra (even a healthy amount) weight that's where it goes first. Perhaps the skins tendency to fold and bend there makes the fur stick out at odd angles regardless of sex. It's hard for me to add evidence I've only had longhairs.

Comment: Yes it's obvious that it's longer, you can even see in the picture that her belly's fur is much shorter than her abdomen.

Comment: Very interesting, both of my siamese do not have the extra fur. However, the Siamese x Feral we have does! could be a breed/fur length thing? Maybe it doesn't look longer on the siamese as they have short fur anyway...

Comment: My cat has it too...
She was a feral Calico kitten who adopted me, she's not fat, she is muscular though... You can see clearly in the picture how long the fur is on her belly area:[![007](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtG9A.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtG9A.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

The fur on the belly of cats is about the same as on the rest of the body, but the combination of loose skin and gravity, and the fact that the fur stands straight out, makes it look longer.

Male and female cats have about the same amount and length of fur on the belly; lactating cats have a bit less fur in the area around the nipples, but the fur length is the same as the males have.

Older cats have more loose skin on the belly than younger cats do, and I think female cats have a tiny bit more loose skin around the mammaries than male cats have in the same area.

Answer (score 1):

Is the white fur, the area of the abdomen? If it is, my cat has the same thing. She's an orange and white tabby and has soft white fur around the abdomen which is longer than the rest. So it's probably more common in most cats.

Comment: Yes that's the area we're talking about

Answer (score 0):

My female cat also has long hair on her stomach, I was thinking it was because they shaved her when they fixed her. Not for sure!

Comment: Did you notice a change? Do you have any pictures of her before her operation and after the hair grew back?